# Creating time lapse images in python

Tags: python, opencv, timelapse

The following code capture an image from webcam, and saves into the disk. I want to write a program which can automate capturing of an image at every 30 seconds until 12 hours. What is the best way to do that?

```
import cv2     
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
image0 = cap.read()[1]
cv2.imwrite('image0.png', image0)
```

Following is the modification based on the answer from @John Zwinck, since I need also to write the image captured every 30 seconds into the disk naming with the time captured:

```
import time, cv2
current_time = time.time()
endtime = current_time + 12*60*60
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while current_time < endtime:    
    img = cap.read()[1]
    cv2.imwrite('img_{}.png'.format(current_time), img)
    time.sleep(30)
```

However, above code could write only the last file over the previous one for each time. Looking for its improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import time
endTime = time.time() + 12*60*60 # 12 hours from now
while time.time() < endTime:
    captureImage()
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: I also need to write the image captured every 30 seconds naming with the time captured

Comment: Great, so try implementing that.  This isn't a code-for-hire-for-free service.  If you get stuck, by all means come back with a new question.

Comment: I see you already figured out how to put the time into the filename.  So you're good now?

Answer (score 0):

Your output image name is the same!!! In the while loop the `current_time` will not change, so it will save each frame with the same name. Replacing `.format(current_time)` to `.format(time.time())` should work.

Replace

`while current_time < endtime:

    img = cap.read()[1]
    cv2.imwrite('img_{}.png'.format(current_time), img)
    time.sleep(30)`

To
`cv2.imwrite('img_{}.png'.format(int(time.time())), img)`